# Get duplicate value in array while ignoring certain values and numbers in front of values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find out if same value in array except for CERTIFICATE OF ANALYSIS  and bellow is my array

```
[0] => 1009
[1] => 1033
[2] => 2052
[3] => ANNEX 4E
[4] => Bill of Lading
[5] => CERTIFICATE OF ANALYSIS 123456
[6] => CERTIFICATE OF ANALYSIS 000999
[7] => CERTIFICATE OF ORIGIN 123456
[8] => CERTIFICATE OF ORIGIN 789934
[9] => DHL - 1387563870
[10] => DHL - 5130431633
```

so after checking I'm expecting bellow result

```
[1] => CERTIFICATE OF ORIGIN 123456
[2] => CERTIFICATE OF ORIGIN 789934
[3] => DHL - 1387563870
[4] => DHL - 5130431633
```

since CERTIFICATE OF ORIGIN appeared two times and DHL appeared  two times, with an exception for CERTIFICATE OF ANALYSIS

i try with bellow code

```
function array_not_unique( $a = array() )
{
  return array_diff_key( $a , array_unique( $a ) );
}
```

but not able to get the out put since there is some number in front of the names. do I need to use regular expression here and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first extract the "key" information using a regular expression, and then store the values by key in an associative array. Finally, get the values from that associative array where a key has more than one associated value:

```
function array_not_unique( $a = [] ) { 
    $byKey = [];
    foreach($a as $val) {
        $key = preg_replace("/[^a-z]+$/i", "", $val);
        if ($key && $key != "CERTIFICATE OF ANALYSIS") $byKey[$key][] = $val;
    }
    $result = [];
    foreach($byKey as $arr) {
        if (count($arr) > 1) $result = array_merge($result, $arr);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant great answer Sir!